# pip freeze doesn't show opencv in Linux/Mint

Tags: python, linux, opencv, pip, freeze

I've installed OpenCV on Linux Mint and I can import it in python

```
(cv_env)➜  cv_env python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
```

But when I want to see it in pip freeze, it doesn't appear:

```
(cv_env)➜  cv_env pip freeze
argparse==1.2.1
caffi==1.0.2
coffee==0.1.0
ffmpeg-python==0.1.6
future==0.16.0
imutils==0.4.3
numpy==1.13.3
pandas==0.20.3
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
scipy==0.19.1
six==1.11.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Also, I tried to import it via PyCharm's Project Interpreter. It wants to installation with pip. (pip install opencv-python and pip install cv2)

When I installed that, I followed [these steps](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/)

What is the problem that I cannot see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those instructions are outdated, and using `apt-get` puts pieces outside of the virtual environment, where `pip` won't see them to freeze.

Within a virtual environment, try

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install opencv-python
```

The `--upgrade` might not be necessary, but has helped me out of weird `pip` failures in the past.